# dataset is taking the date along with time where stored procedure is sending only date

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, sql-server-2008

In sql the stored procedure output  is coming as a column of having only date.but when it comes into c# code in mvc project that table is automatically converts to the datetime.
i cant understand how it is possible.
from sp it comes as date but in dataset it coverts into the datetime.
how to get only date in c# code

Comment: The data type of the column in Dataset may be of DateTime

Comment: There is no date only data type in c#, just ignore the time portion, which in this case will be all zeros anyway.

Comment: Use Substring to extract the date portion

Comment: @BenRobinson, just got your comment right after sending my answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you can convert to a string type

```
string s = dataset1.Tables[0].Rows[rownumber]["datecolumn"].ToString().Replace("00:00:00","");
```

**UPDATE**

You can add new column to hold in `Date-only` format

```
dataset1.Tables[0].Columns.Add("Date");
for(int i=0;i<dataTable1.Rows.Count;i++)
{
    dataset1.Tables[0].Rows[i]["Date"] = dataset1.Tables[0].Rows[rownumber]["datecolumn"].ToString().Replace("00:00:00","");
}
```

Now you can hide the `datecolumn` column and show `Date` column in front end

If you want to sort the table according to date,

```
DataTable dt=dataset1.Tables[0].Copy();
DataView dv=new DataView(dt);
dv.Sort = "datecolumn asc";
dt = dv.ToTable();
dataset1.Tables.Clear();
dataset1.Tables.Add(dt);
```

Comment: thanks bro but i want that string s value to show in gridview.how can i?

Comment: this way you lose the value of making a date or datetime type. as you cannot do filtering, sorting, calculation on that string without parsing it back to date

Comment: This is the way to get the date part from DateTime. It doesn't require to remove the old column(DateTime), which can be used for Date filtration and can be set as hidden field. So internally it will contain 2 columns one as DateTime and another as string. Simple @mGouda

Comment: Keep the old column which have both Date and time as it is because it will act as column of DateTime type which can be used for sorting date. Create a new column with varchar type and do the above conversion.  @bhargav

Comment: @SarathAvanavu, agree :) .. but you can replace .ToString().Replace("00:00:00",""); with .ToShortDateString()

Comment: Yes. Thats too right. It can be done in different ways. Thanks @mGouda

Answer (score 1):

There is no data type in C# for `Date` only.

Rather you use `DateTime` and control the format.

So to show date only use a format like `dd/MM/yyyy`

In your case as the database provide dates only, your .net object will contain time part of the date always set to `"00:00:00"` which does not affect the value of the property and you hide it using above mentioned format

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the type to varchar so C# wont append the time part
`CONVERT(varchar,COLUMN_NAME,105)` 105 or in whichever format you want or if default dont specify